# Grails startup error message

Tags: grails, gant

When I start my Grails-application I get the following error:

WARNING: Configurational method [checksums] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy doesn't exist. Ignoring..
WARNING: Configurational method [inherits] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy doesn't exist. Ignoring..

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have the following:

```
 inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
 checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
```

And later in the file:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
```

Perhaps some kind soul can shed some light on the message and how I can get rid of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those properties were added in 2.0, so it looks like you've copy/pasted some 2.0 project code into a 1.3.x project, or possibly upgraded and then downgraded? Either way, delete both lines and you'll get past this issue, although there may be other copy/paste issues still lurking.